# Why would I turn System.Diagnostics trace autoflush off?

Tags: .net, system.diagnostics

In all my applications, I have always set

```xml
<trace autoflush="true" />
```

Is there any reason why someone would want not to do that?

I guess there is a performance impact, but how big is it?

Comment: _"I guess there is a performance impact, but how big is it?"_ - don't guess, measure.

Comment: It seems with autoflush on the default is 8k blocks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173366/trace-flush-will-data-get-written-to-textwritertracelistener-immediately - if you are manually flushing then you have control, the larger the buffer you allow the less context switching of IO for writes but the bigger the impact of each write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.autoflush.aspx):

> Trace.AutoFlush Property
>
> Gets or sets whether Flush should be called
>   on the Listeners after every write.

For performance reasons, you might prefer flushing less frequently (less IO). The downside of this is, lines that are not flushed will be lost in case of a crash.

Edit: The impact will be proportional to how frequent the trace is written to. If you aren't making a heavy use of it, the performance gain will possibly be ignorable. However, it is generally used in the whole codebase. Measuring is always better.