# Trace.Flush() - Will data get written to TextWriterTraceListener immediately?

Tags: c#, .net

If using auto flush, or flushing manually on each write of message, I noticed something while debugging in Visual studio, I don't see the data written to file even though I enable AutoFlush = true.  The file only gets updated when I stop the debugger.  This led me to believe that the data is only being flushed at certain time, or when the program comes to completion.

Or is this a side effect of debugging and in the actual program it will behave differently?

At what point will data get written? Right away, or after some event, or time?

EDIT:  I do see the output message in the Debug Output windows of Visual Studio, just not in the file.

Comment: Are you using log4net or some other library? Please add the appropriate tags and also include the log4net configuration for your appender if that is what you are using.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain no just basic .net Trace and TraceSource.  But I think I found the reason was the buffer needs to fill up to a certain amount before it can write to file.  When i used a bigger message the file updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an explanation here
[Trace file isn't being created even though TraceEvent is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502960/trace-file-isnt-being-created-even-though-traceevent-is-called)

"Writers flush to disk when their internal buffers fill, if memory serves me the default buffer size is 8KB. This is not a facet of trace listeners, but the underlying file stream it writes to."