# What is the expense of Trace.Flush() in C#?

Tags: c#, logging

Is it necessary to call `Trace.Flush()` in the code? Is that an expensive call?

Thanks.

Comment: Surely it depends on how much is stuck in the queue to be written.... but yes, flushing is a good idea.

Comment: You could call Trace.Flush() once you are done with your Trace.Write type operations.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611189/why-would-i-turn-system-diagnostics-trace-autoflush-off

Comment: A trace listener holds the messages you send it in memory until you Flush() it.

Comment: It depends on the listener.  If it writes the trace info to a file then, yes, flushing is pretty expensive.  Relatively, it still takes well less than the blink of an eye.  Whether that *really* matters to your program is something you have to find out by yourself.